# Browser SWT Linux Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)])

Tags: java, linux, jar, swt, mozilla

I'm developing an SWT `crossplatform` program and in **linux** `(both 32 and 64)` when i try to open a window that have a SWT browser inside i get this error(the program is exported as runnable jar):

```
Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)])
```

I read a lot of questions about this error on internet but i was not able to resolve it.

I tried to set my MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME variable with no luck:
i tried:

```
MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME = /usr/lib/mozilla/
    MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME = /usr/lib/
    MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME = /opt/xulrunner/
    MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME = /tmp/swtlib-32/
```

and the error i got is this everytime:

```
 Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='<path i set before>'] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-mozilla-gtk-3655 in java.library.path
    no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
    /tmp/swtlib-32/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3655.so: libxpcom.so: can not open shared object file: A file or directory that does not exist
    Can't load library: /tmp/swtlib-32/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so
))
```

I tried to:
reinstall Firefox
reinstall xulrunner
reinstall libwebkit with the command: sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0

i tried to set in my code the composite with the embedded browser from 
    SWT.NONE to SWT.MOZILLA

I also tried to set my **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** variable..still no luck

On windows all works fine.

What can i do?

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.